# typealias closure error in swift

Tags: swift, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking in a Swift project.

1 - Typealias the closure:

```
typealias successBlock = (AFHTTPRequestOperation! ,AnyObject!)-> Void
typealias failureBlock = (AFHTTPRequestOperation, NSError!) -> Void
```

2 - Define the function:

```
func getUserInfo(success: (successBlock)!, failure: (failureBlock)!) {
   let path = "https://api.wei.s.json"
   let parameters = ["source":"key"]
   self.GET(path, parameters: parameters, success: success, failure: failure)
}
```

3 - Error:

> Cannot invoke 'GET' with an argument list of type '(String,parameters: [String : String], success: (successBlock)!, failure: (failureBlock)!)'

Thanks for any help.

**EIDT:**

```
typealias failureBlock = (AFHTTPRequestOperation, NSError!) -> Void
```

to

```
typealias failureBlock = (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the parenthesis from `(successBlock)!`?

Comment: it may be that because AFNetworking is an Objective-C library it does not like the swift 'String' type for the 'path' and 'parameters' paramters to the GET method. It may be better to use the swift version of AFNetworking called AlamoFire so you don't run into these types of issue moving forward.

Comment: @Clashsoft same error.

Comment: @deanware Seems not this reason, I tried only block parameters.

Comment: How is `GET` defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it you are missing a ! on the failureBlock typealias definition it is expecting an explicitly unwrapped optional AFHTTPRequestOperation not a standard AFHTTPRequestOperation which are actually different types. I believe it should be,

```
typealias failureBlock = (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void
```

Comment: also implicitly unwrapping the method input parameters seems a bit of a red flag to me, either pass in optionals and use an if let to unwrap them and call GET if they are there and handle the case when they arent or make them non optional.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
func getUserInfo(success: (successBlock)!, failure: (failureBlock)!) {
   let path = "https://api.wei.s.json"
   let parameters = ["source":"key"]
   self.GET(path, parameters: parameters, success: success!, failure: failure!)
}
```

(Note the two "bang" !  on the arguments success and failure.

That's based on the assumption that the GET function expects a closure and not an optional referring to a closure. It might be it. Otherwise, use the keystroke to get method completion on self.GET and see the type that Swift expects. It will tell you where there is an issue.